# Problemas con condición en Ant

Tags: jenkins, ant

Tengo un problema a la hora de hacer una condición con ant, y es que nunca entra en la condición (cuando a veces si debería). El código que estoy utilizando es:

```
<condition property="estado" value="true" >
<or>
<equals arg1="${state}" arg2="STOPPED" />
<equals arg1="${state}" arg2="STOPPING" />
</or>
</condition>
<fail if="${estado}" message="Server parado"/>
```

La variable `state` vale o STARTED, STOPPED o STOPPING (he comprobado que adquiere el valor que debe anteriormente). El problema es que cuando vale STOPPED o STOPPING no entra en el `<condition>` y estado nunca se settea, por lo que nunca me falla la tarea de ant.

He probado poniendo en equals casesensitive y forcestring, y nada. También he probado poniendo:

```
<fail if="estado" message="Server parado"/>
```

y nada.

¿Sabéis por qué puede ser?